# Kalman Filter in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst, kalman-filter

I have a video and I have to locate the position of a ball using the Kalman equations. Suppose the initial position of the ball in the first frame `(xi,yi)` is known.

Please guide me what would be the current position `(currx,curry);` as in the code below in subsequent frames.

What I have so far:

```
R  = [0.2845 0.0045;0.0045 0.0455];
Hi = [1 0 0 0; 0 1 0 0];
Q  = 0.01*eye(4);
Pe = 100*eye(4);
F  = [1 0 0 0; 0 1 0 0; 0 0 1 0; 0 0 0 1];
x  = zeros(569,4);

kfinite = false;
for k = 1:nframes

    % Kalman initialization
    if ~kfinite
        Au    = [xi yi 0 0].';
        currx = xi;
        curry = yi;

    % Prediction 1st equation
    else            
        u  = [x1 y1 0 0].';
        Au = F*x(k-1,:).' + u; 
        currx = xi;
        curry = yi;

    end

    vx = currx-Au(1);
    vy = curry-Au(2);

    xactual      = [currx curry vx vy].';
    xactualnext  = F*xactual;
    ydesirednext = Hi*xactualnext;

    % Prediction 2nd equation
    pp = F*Pe*F.' + Q;   

    % correction 3rd equation
    K = pp*Hi.' / (Hi*pp*Hi.' + R); 

    % correction 4th equation
    Anu = Au + K*(ydesirednext - Hi*Au); 

    % correction 5th equation
    Pe = (eye(4) - K*Hi)*pp;  
    x1 = Anu(1);
    x2 = Anu(2);

    kfinite = true;

end
```

Comment: Maybe I just don't see it - but I can't locate where in your implementation is the time evolution.  Anyway in the matlab documentation is a nice example for a kalman filter: http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/kalman-filtering.html (scroll down to time varying design) - why don't you go from there?

Comment: I've made your code more readable. Please make a habit from now on to do this with ***ANY*** code you write -- you will likely be spending quite some time *reading* your code, much more than it takes to write it. Better make reading it as easy as possible. There is no paper to save, so please don't save up on whitespace.

Comment: What if I don't use time evolution in my code. kindly guide me.

Comment: this might help you http://www.mathworks.ch/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42257-kalman-filter-demo-for-ball-tracking